# read a line from file and if pattern match then delete it from it in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file place.txt with the content say:

```
I want to go Rome. Will Go.
I want to go Rome. Will Not Go.
I want to go Rome. Will Not Go.
I want to go Rome. Will Go.
I want to go India. Will Not Go.
I want to go India. Will Not Go.
I want to go Rome. Will Go.
```

I want to read this file and match the lines with the pattern "I want to go Rome." and omit those lines matching the pattern from this file in perl.

My sample code is:

```
$file = new IO::File;
$file->open("<jobs.txt") or die "Cannot open jobs.txt";

while(my $line = $file->getline){
    next if $line =~ m{/I want to go Rome/};
    print $line;
}

close $file;
```

Note: My file would be a big one. Can we use sed or awk?

Comment: The problem is probably double brackets. Use `m{...}` or `m/.../` or `/.../` but not `m{/.../}`. It tries find pattern containing '/'.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as

```
perl -ine'print unless /I want to go Rome/'
```

If you prefer script

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use constant FILENAME => 'jobs.txt';

open my $in, '<', FILENAME;

while (<$in>) {
    if ( $. == 1 ) {    # you need to do this after read first line
                        # $in will keep i-node with the original file
        open my $out, '>', FILENAME;
        select $out;
    }
    print unless /I want to go Rome/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

grep -v 'I want to go Rome' jobs.txt

Is much simpler still to write.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$0~/I want to go Rome/' jobs.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

open my $file, "<", "jobs.txt" or die "Cannot open jobs.txt : $!";
open my $outtemp, ">", "out.temp" or die "Unable to open file : $!\n"; # create a temporary file to write the lines which doesn't match pattern.

while(my $line = <$file>)
{
    next if $line =~ m/I want to go Rome/; # ignore lines which matches pattern
    print $outtemp $line; # write the rest lines in temp file.
}
close $file;
close $outtemp;
move("out.temp", "jobs.txt"); # move temp file into original file.
```

Comment: how to use awk in this perl file to update the same file after the pattern matches.

Comment: howto delete the line that matched the pattern from the file

Comment: @user3616128: You can't make holes in file so you have to either move rest of file forward to fill the hole or much better make copy.

Comment: I think this answer might be improved with a little more explanation as to what it's doing.

Comment: @user3616128 : I do not use `awk`, in `perl` have a look at edited code.